# How to read in a file of numbers into an array list in Java

Tags: java, file-io

I want to be able to read in a map from a file that looks something like:

> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
>
> 0, 0, 1, 0, 0
>
> 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
>
> 0, 1, 1, 1, 0
>
> 0, 0, 1, 1, 0

And create an array list that looks like:

> {[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>
> [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
>
> [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
>
> [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
>
> [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]}

I have tried using br.readLine() but it appears to be getting stuck but not throwing an error in the middle.

> public static int[][] loadFile() throws IOException{
>
> ```
>     FileReader in = new FileReader(Main.currentFilePath + Main.currentFile);
>     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
>     String line;
>     int [] intArray = {};
>     int [][] fileArray = {};
>     int j = 0;
>     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
>         List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(line.split(",")));
>         String[] stringArray = stringList.toArray(new String[0]);
>         List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
>         System.out.println("RRRRR");
>         for(int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++) {
>             Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stringArray[i]);
>             System.out.println("GGGGG");
>             while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
>                 intList.add(scanner.nextInt());
>                 intArray = intList.parallelStream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
>                 System.out.println("FFFF");
>             }
>             System.out.println(fileArray[j][i]);
>             fileArray[j][i] = intArray[i];
>         }
>         j++;
>     }
>     return fileArray;
>     
> }
> ```

Comment: .... and the `"error in the middle..."` is???

Comment: It throws `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` because your `fileArray` has a length of `0`, it's impossible for you to add any new rows/columns to it

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I think you misread it, I'm mysteriously getting no error, but the use of print statements tells me the program simply stops at fileArray[j][i] = intArray[i];

Comment: @MadProgrammer So if I use an array list it should work?

Comment: Which suggests that you have an empty catch block somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is, you're declaring an array of `0` length (no elements), which makes it impossible to add any elements to it.

```
int [][] fileArray = {};
```

Unless you know in advance EXACTLY the number of rows/columns you need, arrays are not very helpful, instead, you could make use of a `List` of some kind, for example...

```
List<int[]> rows = new ArrayList<>(5);
int maxCols = 0;
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("Test.txt")))) {
    String text = null;
    while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(text);
        String[] parts = text.split(",");
        int[] row = new int[parts.length];
        maxCols = Math.max(maxCols, row.length);
        for (int col = 0; col < parts.length; col++) {
            row[col] = Integer.parseInt(parts[col].trim());
        }
        rows.add(row);
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

int[][] map = new int[rows.size()][maxCols];
for (int row = 0; row < rows.size(); row++) {
    map[row] = rows.get(row);
}
```

My "personal" gut feeling is simply not to bother with the arrays at all and simply make use of compound `List`s...

```
List<List<Integer>> rows = new ArrayList<>(5);
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("Test.txt")))) {
    String text = null;
    while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(text);
        String[] parts = text.split(",");
        List<Integer> row = new ArrayList<>(parts.length);
        for (String value : parts) {
            row.add(Integer.parseInt(value.trim()));
        }
        rows.add(row);
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the same with Java 8 magic

```
String filePath = "input.txt";
List<Integer[]> output = new ArrayList<>();

try(Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath)) ) {

    stream.filter(line -> line != null && !line.isEmpty())
    .forEach(line->output.add(
        Arrays.stream(line.split(", "))//assuming that 2 numbers are separated by a comma followed by a white space
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .toArray(size -> new Integer[size])
    ));

} catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

output.forEach(s -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s)));
```

**Output**

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```